# How to dynamically update Selenium methods without restarting the webdriver?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

I have a Selenium bot that interacts with EA Sports FIFA 21 web app, where you can buy and sells in-game football players. The interface looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXp0z.jpg).

Lets say my original program was a single script that:

1. login() - logged into the platform
2. goToTransferMarket() - navigated to the ‘market search’ page
3. inputSearchParameters(playername) - inputted my search parameters to search
4. clickSearch() - clicked Search button
5. evaluateResults(buy_price) - evaluated results and bought players cheaper than buy price

If any method failed, I’d  have to quit and restart from scratch. To fix this, I built a [tkinter GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K2Y6.png) with buttons for each function that executes in their own thread. This way If a function fails, like clicking the search button, I can manually perform the action and proceed to test the subsequent methods.

But still, to fix the broken methods, I have to restart the program from scratch which requires a tedious login process to fix something as simple as forgetting to cast a string to an integer. Logging in a lot also draws unwanted attention.

**Given that I’m already logged in during the current testing session, is there a way to recompile my program and ‘grab’ the existing webdriver session?**

**Even better, is it possible to dynamically change my functions and update them with an ‘update with latest code’ button in my GUI?**

The 'player list' box in my GUI writes to a textfile, which allows me to change who the bot is searching for in real time. The textfile is passed to the main bot search method when I click the "Bid using list" button. This is what made me wonder if I can set it up to somehow recompile parts of my code in a separate thread and keep my existing webdriver session. Any help would be amazing thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a infinite while loop and try catch to make sure your test never fails else :

If you are using chrome :

you can connect to existing chrome session using debuuger address, so start the chrome with specified debugging port from cmd

Start chrome with debug port: (In windows , search for other os how to start chrome in a specific debug port)

`<path>\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=1559`

And in selenium use :

JAVA:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1559");

WebDriver browser=new ChromeDriver(options);`
```

Python :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1559")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```